# What does "word for word" syntax mean in Python?

Tags: python, gensim

I see the following script snippet from the [gensim tutorial page](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html).

What's the syntax of **word for word** in below Python script?

```
>> texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist]
>>          for document in documents]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  The code you posted loops through every element in `document.lower.split()` and creates a new list that contains only the elements that meet the `if` condition.  It does this for each document in `documents`.

Try it out...

```
elems = [1, 2, 3, 4]
squares = [e*e for e in elems]  # square each element
big = [e for e in elems if e > 2]  # keep elements bigger than 2
```

As you can see from your example, list comprehensions can be nested.

Answer (score 5):

That is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). An easier example might be:

```
evens = [num for num in range(100) if num % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm quite sure i saw that line in some NLP applications.

This list comprehension:

```
[[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist] for document in documents]
```

is the same as

```
ending_list = [] # often known as document stream in NLP.
for document in documents: # Loop through a list.
  internal_list = [] # often known as a a list tokens
  for word in document.lower().split():
    if word not in stoplist:
      internal_list.append(word) # this is where the [[word for word...] ...] appears
  ending_list.append(internal_list)
```

Basically you want a list of documents that contains a list of tokens. So by looping through the documents,

```
for document in documents:
```

you then split each document into tokens

```
  list_of_tokens = []
  for word in document.lower().split():
```

and then make a list of of these tokens:

```
    list_of_tokens.append(word)
```

For example:

```
>>> doc = "This is a foo bar sentence ."
>>> [word for word in doc.lower().split()]
['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence', '.']
```

It's the same as:

```
>>> doc = "This is a foo bar sentence ."
>>> list_of_tokens = []
>>> for word in doc.lower().split():
...   list_of_tokens.append(word)
... 
>>> list_of_tokens
['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence', '.']
```

Comment: Glad the answer helped =)